# How restart Cron jobs in a Magento 2 Store Migration

Tags: magento2

I have migrated my Magento store 2.3.1 from the server. I have migrated database and folder with all files. What do I have to do with cron jobs? This is my error in logs:

```
[2019-11-19 11:21:16] main.ERROR: Cron Job indexer_update_all_views has an error: SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_store` SELECT `ip_tmp`.* FROM `catalog_product_index_price_store_temp` AS `ip_tmp` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `tax_class_id` = VALUES(`tax_class_id`), `price` = VALUES(`price`), `final_price` = VALUES(`final_price`), `min_price` = VALUES(`min_price`), `max_price` = VALUES(`max_price`), `tier_price` = VALUES(`tier_price`). Statistics: {"sum":0,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":0,"realmem_start":170131456,"emalloc_start":157612720} [] []
[2019-11-19 11:21:16] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_store` SELECT `ip_tmp`.* FROM `catalog_product_index_price_store_temp` AS `ip_tmp` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `tax_class_id` = VALUES(`tax_class_id`), `price` = VALUES(`price`), `final_price` = VALUES(`final_price`), `min_price` = VALUES(`min_price`), `max_price` = VALUES(`max_price`), `tier_price` = VALUES(`tier_price`) {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_store` SELECT `ip_tmp`.* FROM `catalog_product_index_price_store_temp` AS `ip_tmp` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `tax_class_id` = VALUES(`tax_class_id`), `price` = VALUES(`price`), `final_price` = VALUES(`final_price`), `min_price` = VALUES(`min_price`), `max_price` = VALUES(`max_price`), `tier_price` = VALUES(`tier_price`) at /var/www/magento/app/code/Bss/MultiStoreViewPricingPriceIndexer/Model/Indexer/Product/Price/Action/Rows.php:51, Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Adapter\\DeadlockException(code: 1213): SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_store` SELECT `ip_tmp`.* FROM `catalog_product_index_price_store_temp` AS `ip_tmp` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `tax_class_id` = VALUES(`tax_class_id`), `price` = VALUES(`price`), `final_price` = VALUES(`final_price`), `min_price` = VALUES(`min_price`), `max_price` = VALUES(`max_price`), `tier_price` = VALUES(`tier_price`) at /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:589, Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 40001): SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_store` SELECT `ip_tmp`.* FROM `catalog_product_index_price_store_temp` AS `ip_tmp` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `tax_class_id` = VALUES(`tax_class_id`), `price` = VALUES(`price`), `final_price` = VALUES(`final_price`), `min_price` = VALUES(`min_price`), `max_price` = VALUES(`max_price`), `tier_price` = VALUES(`tier_price`) at /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235, PDOException(code: 40001): SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction at /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228)"} []
```

Any idea to fix that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to install cron in your server by executing the below command.

```
bin/magento cron:install [--force]
```

After installing cron in your server you need to truncate the `cron_schedule` table flush the cache.

After flush cache, you need to run cron with executing the below command.

```
bin/magento cron:run [--group="<cron group name>"]
```

Where `--group` specifies the cron group to run (omit this option to run cron for all groups)

To run the indexing cron job, you can execute the below command.

```
bin/magento cron:run --group index
```

To run the default cron job, you can execute the below command.

```
bin/magento cron:run --group default
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Most welcome if you face any type of issue contact me on skype

Comment: Thanks! but I can't find you on Skype!

Comment: tusharlathiya1996 This is my skype id